# Module not found: Can't resolve './components/player' in '.../score-board-app/src/components'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I use Create-React-App to build a small React application. The full code is stored in [github](https://github.com/juan-coding/score-board-app)

My file structure:

```
src
  components
    Players.js
    Player.js
App.css
App.js
index.css
index.js
...
```

*App.js:*

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';// used to fix the error: 'PropTypes' is not defined
import Header from './components/Header';
import Players from './components/Players';

const App = (props) => (
  <div className="scoreboard">
    <Header title={props.title} />
    <Players />
  </div>
  );

App.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};


export default App;
```

*Player.js:*

```
import React from 'react';

const Player = (props) => (
  <div className="player">
    <div className="player-name">
      Jim Hoskins
    </div>
    <div className="player-score">
      <div className="counter">
        <button className="counter-action decrement"> - </button>
        <div className="counter-score">31</div>
        <button className="counter-action increment"> + </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Player;
```

*Players.js:*

```
import React from 'react';
import Player from './components/Player';

const Players = () => (
  <div className="players">
    <div className="player">
      <div className="player-name">
        Jim Hoskins
      </div>
      <div className="player-score">
        <div className="counter">
          <button className="counter-action decrement"> - </button>
          <div className="counter-score">31</div>
          <button className="counter-action increment"> + </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="player">
      <div className="player-name">
        Juan Li
      </div>
      <div className="player-score">
        <div className="counter">
          <button className="counter-action decrement"> - </button>
          <div className="counter-score">30</div>
          <button className="counter-action increment"> + </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)

export default Players;
```

And the line `import Player from './components/Player';` leads to this error: 
[image]
But if I put this line on top of `App.js` file, it doesn't report such compiling error. I really want to know what's the issue indeed with my code?

Comment: Not the reason for issue, but a little tip when creating modules, keep all module names lowercase it saves headaches later.. :)

Comment: You'll get an error for your imports Header/Players in App.js as well since they are under /src/components and not just /components

Comment: @Keith I write component name with capital letter because it's suggested by the teacher from an online course.

Comment: Yes, write the component name in capitals, just not the module name.  eg. `import Players from './players';` If you look at NPM you will notice not many with capitals, the main reason is OS's treat case differently, and the consensus for safety, is just keep all module names lowercase.  eg. in windows `Player` and `player` will refer to the same file, but will import as 2 separate modules, and if you have any module statics they will be duplicated.  So get the case slightly wrong on another import, could potentially make for very hard to debug applications.

Comment: @iceveda06  No error occurs because 'App.js' is sitting the same along with the directory as 'components' rather than 'src'. And as I'm just told that './' represent current directory. So ' import player from './components/player' works fine. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your file path is wrong. `Player` is in the same folder as `Players`, so you need to just say `import Player from './Player'`

Comment: I thought './' indicate the 'src' directory'. Could you please explain it a little bit about the relative path?

Comment: `./` just indicates the current directory. so from within the src directory, if you wanted to point to `/src/components/Player`, you would say `./components/Player`. From within the `./components` directory, you would just go `./Player`. If you're familiar with using the command line, and using `.` and `..` to refer to current and parent directories, it is the same concept here.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete the node_modules directory
- Delete the package-lock.json file
- Run npm install
- Run npm start

Comment: Could you explain why you believe this works? Looking at the question it appears the missing module is not a node_module but rather a project file.

Comment: when you are using absolute path and copy hole project from one place to another then this types of errors are occures and cannot import the component becasue package-lock.json hold previous path when package-lock.json file deleted and again install npm then automatically set path of absolute in package-lock.json file.when package-lock.json file new created then automatically problem resolve